# Is it possible to call Leaflet API functions with ipyleaflet in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, leaflet

I'm learning to use the [ipyleaflet library](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Jupyter notebook. The library works well, but I can't find from the API documentation but a small subset of functions if I compare with the [documentation of Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html) itself. I did try to run the following piece of code in Jupyter:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map

m = Map(center=(59, 21), zoom=7)

print(m.getBounds())
```

from which I get the following error:

[image]

I used conda to install the ipyleaflet-library to my Jupyter environment.

**My question** is (did not find answer with quick Googling): Is it possible to call and use the full properties of the Leaflet API in Jupyter with ipyleaflet? If yes, then what steps should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use the full API of LeafletJS in ipyleaflet. ipyleaflet has its own Python API, we try to expose the same API as much as we can but it is not always possible or sometimes it does not make sense to expose some features.

If you think something is really missing, please open an issue on the ipyleaflet repository and I would be happy to guide you into implementing it.

Comment: thank you very much for your help :) Maybe I will in the future.